# Dynamic function for multiple filtering conditions

Tags: r, function, filter

I'm trying to create a function which allow me to filter my `df` in a dynamic way; e.g., imposing conditions to only part of my `df`'s columns, setting different thresholds every time, etc..

Here is an example. Assume this is how my `df` looks like:

```
 col1   col2   col3
 TRUE    0.2   0.5
 TRUE    0.3   0.7
 FALSE   0.7   1.5
```

So, If I want to impose 2 different filters over my `df`, I'll need to write 2 lines:

```
df[df$col1 == TRUE & df$col2 > 0.5]
df[df$col2 < 0.3 & df$col3 > 0.6]
```

Now assume I have a `df` with many columns. I'm looking for something which will allow me to avoid writing the whole line again and again (with different selections); for example, something like that (`my_selection` is a function):

```
my_selection (data = df, col1, ==, TRUE, col2, >, 0.5)
my_selection (data = df, col2, <, 0.3, col3, >, 0.6)
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `?subset`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus How can I use `subset` in a dynamic way? I want to be able to call this function once with conditions on `col1` and `col2` and in other time with `col2` and `col3` (etc...)

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean with calling a function in a dynamic way. So far, I only see that you want to subset a data.frame using 3 different conditions. What would those dynamic calls look like?

Comment: @docendodiscimus I tried to write it differently.. hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the interactive function on that one:

Here's an example with another dataset:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)


employee_sel<- select.list( unique(employee), graphics = TRUE, multiple = TRUE, title = "Select one or more" )
salary_sel<- select.list( as.character(unique(salary)), graphics = TRUE, multiple = TRUE, title = "Select one or more" )
employ_sel<- select.list( as.character(unique(startdate)), graphics = TRUE, multiple = TRUE, title = "Select one or more" )
```